# SqlServerUnitTest with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a database that created with sqlserver 2008, I want create unit test for it in vs2010 but when I create a sqlserver 2008 project and i am connected to my database and database is loaded,then I am clicking on stored procedure to create unit test but this option is in active.
I have understood that warning in stored procedure is caused it. but my project is big and I don't know how I can build and deploy it without error.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect walkthru how to do that is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atverma/archive/2010/07/28/how-to-unit-test-sql-server-2008-database-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

**BUT**

this task can be made much simpler:

You can set up a folder with the test scripts and after it create a simple test unit to run these scripts one by one, faulting the unit test in case an error with exception, containing name of script ran and original error from sql server engine.

Comment: Dear friend The create unit test option is disable because of warning(I Think)

Comment: I want create unit test step by step but the create unit test in this project is disable.
my example project work well but real project not.